# Try statement not returning value in Python 2.7

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to take a list of community types and retrieve the information from a website. However, the try statement presents problems. I need to include the try statement because there are community types in the list that might not be found. When I run the code without the try statement, the code works. But when included doesn't work and always returns the exception.

```
import selenium ## web retrieval
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains ## needed 

comm = ['Colorado Plateau Mixed Low Sagebrush Shrubland','Nowhere Land']

for names in comm:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://explorer.natureserve.org/servlet/NatureServe?init=Ecol")
    SciName = driver.find_element_by_name('nameSpec')
    SciName.send_keys(names)
    checkbox = driver.find_element_by_name('noPunct')
    checkbox.click() ### unselect box
    SciName.submit() ## this submits it
    try: SciName = driver.find_element_by_link_text(names) #
    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        print names
        print "Exception found"
        driver.quit()
        continue
    SciName.click() ## enter this bad boy
    print "I made it"
    driver.quit() ### close the open window
    print names
```

Any thoughts on why this might be happening? I have used the same code on another web page and it worked fine.

Comment: does not work how? According to the error I see it cannot find an element `Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Colorado Plateau Mixed Low Sagebrush Shrubland"}` and `Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Nowhere Land"}`

Comment: Can you include the exception in your question using exception object`except .... as e: print str(e)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing the error `e` returns:

```
Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Colorado Plateau Mixed Low Sagebrush Shrubland"}`
```

and

```
Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link    text","selector":"Nowhere Land"}
```

The page has not loaded before you try to look for the element which can be verified by adding a time.sleep:

```
SciName.submit() ## this submits it
time.sleep(2)
```

You will see the first succeeds but some still fail as you get *No records matched your search criteria* so there is not link to click.

If you use `EC.presence_of_element_located` and print the errors you will see exactly what is happening.

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT,names))
)
    SciName = driver.find_element_by_link_text(names)
except (selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException,selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException) as e:
    print(e)
```

You need to also import the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

running the code without the try/except fails every time.

Comment: Very clear explanation that both solved the problem and demonstrated what I was doing wrong.